# Array Value as Variable Name

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I recently found another stackoverflow question with the following:

```
$segments = array(
"key1"    =>"111",
"key2"    =>"222",
"key3"    =>"333",
"key4"    =>"444"
);
```

I want to have these:

```
$key1 has the value of  "111";

$key2 has the value of  "222";

$key3 has the value of  "333";

$key4 has the value of  "444";
```

The answer was to use `extract($segments)`.

I would like to achieve something not to dissimilar, I have the following array

```
 $test = array('hello','world');
```

I ideally want to loop through them and use the array value as the variable name, for example:

```
$test2 = array('hello','world');
foreach($test as $v)
{
   $$v = $v;
}
```

Therefore after the loop I could echo say `$hello` and this would result in the output `hello`.

Can anyone tell me how I could achieve this. If there is a method without a loop etc then great. I realise my example can be done differently so that this question is redundant, but I ask out of curiosity and for my knowledge.

Comment: I'm just wondering how this would even be useful.

Comment: Your code is working. Why do you search for another answer

Comment: @AdamCherti OP wants `extract(array('hello','world'))`, which won't work. Essentially, OP wants to do `$hello = 'hello'; $world = 'world';`

Comment: I know but the loop he did is doing the work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are better and you rarely if ever need `extract` or variable variables, but this is a way (just for knowledge sake):

```
$test2 = array('hello','world');
extract(array_combine($test2, $test2));
```

Comment: Perfect works like a charm, I was wondering if you needed to put $test2 for each variable in the array, but I have tested this and obviously not, added a new element to the array and works as expected. Many thanks will accept your answer shortly, making me wait at the mo.